# Does this minmax function has a good efficiency?

Tags: c#

To be requested 10 numbers from the user find the min and max number without using arrays. Strings should not be count and will give an error, however program will continue to calculate the min and max if some of the value has provided.

I solved the question but what I'm wondering to know if it is a good solution.

```
public static void MinMax()
{
        double minSayi = 0;
        double maxSayi = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sayı Giriniz: ");

            bool isNumber = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out double sayi);

            if (isNumber)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    minSayi = sayi;
                    maxSayi = sayi;
                } 
                else
                {
                    if (sayi < minSayi)
                    {
                        minSayi = sayi;
                    }

                    if (sayi > maxSayi)
                    {
                        maxSayi = sayi;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Gecersiz sayi girdiniz.");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("*********************");
        Console.WriteLine($"Min sayi: {minSayi}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Max sayi: {maxSayi}");
        Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I expect the output of (1, ... 10) => min = 1; max  = 10;

Comment: Seems fine, and you say it's working. If you really want a code-review, check out https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Should it be better if I cut the i == 0 part to the out of the for loop? Which can be done but makes the code repeat. On the other hand, it will not check i == 0 statement for all values. That makes me a bit confused.

Comment: @GONCAŞİLİK but if you try to cut i == 0 out of the loop you miss the case when first input is not a valid number. So, to my mind, current solution is fine.

Comment: Yes, actually that was the reason why I conclude on the current.

Comment: You can change initialization. Make 'double minSayi = double.MaxValue;' and vice versa for max value. Making this you can remove the first loop condition. Any minimum number will be less than max possible value.

Comment: `double minSayi = double.MaxValue; double maxSayi = 0; minSayi = Math.Min(minSayi, sayi); maxSayi = Math.Max(maxSayi, sayi);`